# Custom avatars in wordpress comments?

Tags: plugin-development, comments, facebook, avatar

I'm looking for a way to let people connect with facebook when posting comments, and to use their facebook avatars as the avatar for the comments. How can this be done? Do I need to create a seperate user account for those people, or is their a way to simply store an avatar url for each comment that's posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three simple steps to generate a Facebook Avatar:

1. Create an extra field in your comment form for the user's facebook
   profile (see e.g. [WP Engineer](http://wpengineer.com/2214/adding-input-fields-to-the-comment-form/) for a code example and how to)
2. If the user filled out this field, get the facebook avatar
   ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821061/facebook-api-how-do-i-get-a-facebook-users-profile-image-through-the-fb-api))
3. Replace the WP avatar with
   your facebook avatar if a fb profile url is set

All together in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/4426620) (**PHP5.3 required!**). Tested with WP3.5 and FireFox/Chrome

**Hint:** It is strongly advised  to read the code comments. There are several informations how to configure the plugin e.g. in the functions.php.

Comment: tyvm! ---------